# Airflow initdb slot_pool does not exists

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I'm facing an issue with **airflow** initialization on postgres backend

**Ubuntu : 18.04.1**

**Airflow : v1.10.6**

**Postgres : 10.10**

**Python 3.6**

And when I run

```
airflow initdb
```

I get

```
    [2019-11-22 10:17:23,564] {db.py:368} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "airflow.slot_pool" does not exist
LINE 2: FROM airflow.slot_pool
             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 1131, in initdb
    db.initdb(settings.RBAC)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 106, in initdb
    upgradedb()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 377, in upgradedb
    add_default_pool_if_not_exists()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 90, in add_default_pool_if_not_exists
    if not Pool.get_pool(Pool.DEFAULT_POOL_NAME, session=session):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/pool.py", line 44, in get_pool
    return session.query(Pool).filter(Pool.pool == pool_name).first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3265, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3043, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3367, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3392, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1250, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "airflow.slot_pool" does not exist
LINE 2: FROM airflow.slot_pool
             ^

[SQL: SELECT airflow.slot_pool.id AS airflow_slot_pool_id, airflow.slot_pool.pool AS airflow_slot_pool_pool, airflow.slot_pool.slots AS airflow_slot_pool_slots, airflow.slot_pool.description AS airflow_slot_pool_description
FROM airflow.slot_pool
WHERE airflow.slot_pool.pool = %(pool_1)s
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: {'pool_1': 'default_pool', 'param_1': 1}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

I've tried deleting / recreating database and user rights (with search_path as said in doc). My postgres is accessible and well configured as tables have been previously created by airflow before the crash ;)

Any ideas?

I've made a try with with Airflow 1.10.2 and it work smoothly with postgres backend.

Comment: I've downgrade my Airflow version to 1.10.2.

Answer (score 4):

This is might be because of examples. Try `load_examples = False` in airflow.cfg
andrun `airflow upgradedb` or `airflow resetdb`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

`airflow resetdb`

> `airflow initdb`: Initialize the metadata database
>
> `airflow resetdb`: Burn down and rebuild the metadata database
>
> `airflow upgradedb`: Apply missing migrations - this is also idempotent and safe but it tracks migrations so if your tables aren't in the state that alembic thinks that they are in you would need to find that "state" and edit that

Most importantly, if you have any connections or variables set they **will** be deleted if you run this.

Comment: this just gives me a different error: `psycopg2.errors.DuplicateColumn: column "operator" of relation "task_instance" already exists`

Comment: i have this same error too. I happened when I downgraded back to 1.10.7 after an upgrade to 1.10.10. How did you fix yours without resetdb?

Comment: You could try running `airflow upgradedb`

Answer (score 1):

Airflow uses default backend SQLite, and have default tables(like `slot_pool`) there. So if you consider to use another backend like `postgres` you should at least add these default tables there.

```
$ airflow initdb
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kinda late, but I experienced the same trying $ **airflow db init** against a MySQL 8 backend, and got a similar error.

Turned out that there was a mismatch in my configuration:
The database was named airflow_db, so I had
`sql_alchemy_conn = mysql+mysqlconnector://airflow:******@localhost:3306/airflow_db`, but a few lines down in the **airflow.cfg**, I also had the line
`sql_alchemy_schema = airflow`