# Airflow stops scheduling tasks after a few days of runs

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

Airflow Version 2.0.2

I have three schedulers running in a kubernetes cluster running the `CeleryExecutor` with a postgres backend. Everything seems to run fine for a couple of weeks, but then the airflow scheduler stops scheduling some tasks. I've done an `airflow db reset` followed by an `airflow db init` and a fresh deployment of the airflow-specific images. Below are some of the errors I've received from logging in the database:

According to https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19811 the `slot_pool` issue is expected behavior, but I cannot figure out why DAGs suddenly stop being scheduled on time. For reference, there are ~500 DAGs being run every 15 minutes.

`LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out`

```
STATEMENT:  SELECT slot_pool.pool AS slot_pool_pool, slot_pool.slots AS slot_pool_slots                                     
FROM slot_pool FOR UPDATE NOWAIT
```

The `slot_pool` table looks like this:

```
select * from slot_pool;
 id |     pool     | slots | description
----+--------------+-------+--------------
  1 | default_pool |   128 | Default pool
(1 row)
```

I have looked at several posts, but none of the posts seem to explain the issue or provide a solution. Below are a few of them:

[Airflow initdb slot_pool does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991074/airflow-initdb-slot-pool-does-not-exists)

[Running multiple Airflow Schedulers cause Postgres locking issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443489/running-multiple-airflow-schedulers-cause-postgres-locking-issues)

[Airflow tasks get stuck at "queued" status and never gets running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853013/airflow-tasks-get-stuck-at-queued-status-and-never-gets-running)